# How to retrieve shopify endpoint api with sveltekit

Tags: shopify, sveltekit

I'm trying to get access to my Shopify API from SvelteKit, so I used an .env:

```
VITE_SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_API_TOKEN = ""
VITE_SHOPIFY_API_ENDPOINT = ""
```

which allows me to configure the whole environment.

Then I use:

```
export const postToShopify = async ({ query, variables }) => {
    try {
        // @ts-ignore
        const result = await fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_SHOPIFY_API_ENDPOINT, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-Shopify-Storefront-Access-Token': import.meta.env.VITE_SHOPIFY_STOREFRONT_API_TOKEN
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ query, variables })
        }).then((res) => res.json());

        if (result.errors) {
            console.log({ errors: result.errors });
        } else if (!result || !result.data) {
            console.log({ result });
            return 'No results found.';
        }

        return result.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};
```

But I don't know how to put in `"VITE_SHOPIFY_API_ENDPOINT = """`.

Comment: Please use proper grammar when asking or answering. SO is not a discussion board, it's more like an encyclopedia of questions and their answers, where grammar matters. See [ask] and "[Priority of grammar, spelling and punctuation in questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/306797/128421)".

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv) npm package.

Install: `npm install dotenv --save`

Import: `import 'dotenv/config'`

Use: `process.env.VITE_SHOPIFY_API_ENDPOINT`

Comment: Please go through the [Stack Overflow tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It will give you sufficient reputation to use comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the package in use and how this provides a solution to the question.

Comment: @theTinMan I'm not sure I understand—I went through the tour but did not receive any reputation.

Comment: @Tyler2P—I tried to be as concise as possible and show one-liners for how one would both import and use the package—I am new to answering questions, please feel free to edit my response so I can see more clearly what you mean.